# Delete duplicate elements retrieved by JSoup scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

In my scraping function, I retrieve the links present in the DOM.

```
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    if(linkHref.contains("/blog/")){
        System.out.print("Link: " + linkHref + "\n");
    }
}
```

This works well.

What I want to do know is **delete the duplicate links within the Elements object**.

Is it possible? If not, I'll easily find a workaround using an array of string, but I prefer idiomatic solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elements that JSOUP extracts from a DOM are not equal to each other, even if they contain the exact same tags, properties and values. This did create confusion in the past and was briefly changed and then created even more confusion as I recall (see https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/561)

So you should go with a solution outside JSOUP. Depending on what you actually consider equal elements, you can fill a HashSet with the appropriate stuff. If if is all properties and values of the JSOUP anchor elements, then you need to do a little extra work in case you can't guarantee the order of properties in HTML elements. So you could do:

```
Initialize a HashSet
for each link Element:
extract all properties and values
sort the properties
concatenate to each property its value
concatenate all perperty-value strings
see if the perperty-value string is contained in your Hashset
if yes you found a new Element, so put it in the HashSet and do whatever you want
continue with next Elememnt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this using `HashSet`. `HashSet` is a data structure that store unique set of elements so if there are duplicate links you won't have them in your HashSet.

```
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    if(linkHref.contains("/blog/")){
        set.add(linkHref);
        System.out.print("Link: " + linkHref + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should add a check if the linkHref is already in the HashSet, otherwise the set has not much meaning

Comment: @luksch Set itself has a property that it contains only unique elements. If you want to know about Set check here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Comment: please clarify how to convert set back to Elements ?